# Renaming thousands of text files using regular expression

Tags: regex

I have over 30K plain text files with different name formats residing on hundreds of directories and sub-directories in my Windows drive H. Following are examples of those files' names:
SQT-DIR-S43-1.txt
KT-BL-S36-ALL-4.txt
TMCR-S37-3OP-3W52-1.txt
TT-BL-S30-SH-1.txt

I can rename using a bulk renaming facility. However, **a smart regex** is needed to enable me rename all those files so that the last number after the hyphen to have letter "T" added to it. Hence the previous four examples would be like:

SQT-DIR-S43-T1.txt
KT-BL-S36-ALL-T4.txt
TMCR-S37-3OP-3W52-T1.txt
TT-BL-S30-SH-T1.txt

**Please note that file extension is not included in the file's name.**

Any assistance with this issue is highly appreciated.
Many thanks in advance.

J.

Comment: What tools are available? Do you have a bash, sed, perl, nix-find... or is the solution restricted to widnows things, powershell, windows-find... ? What  tools did you experiment with? This influence among other things the regex flavor you need to use. Do you at least have a regex which achieves the desired change to filename?

Comment: Have you made an attempt to come up with a regex of your own? It really doesn't get much easier than this.

Comment: What do you want to match? Does your tool support replacing with regex?

Comment: I'm using bulk renaming utility for Windows that could be downloaded from <htttp://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/> which supports replacing with regex, Windows flavour. Yes, certainly I tried many regex ideas to reach the last digit in the file name located after the last hyphen, but actually couldn't due to other hyphens existing in the name's structure.<br> Asking for help is my last resort after all attempts result in vain.

Comment: Just to add, I can use cmd and powershell once the correct command is suggested, thanks.

Comment: @JosefMiller Something like this may be [`(.*)(\d\..*)`](https://regex101.com/r/8oQLOG/3)

Comment: I tried: Match criteria is `(.*)([0-9]{1,})` whilst replace is `\1T\2` but it doesn't work on file names with more than one digit at the end; eg SQT-DIR-S43-11.txt file name will be SQT-DIR-S43-1T1.txt. how can I define the last digit so that letter T is added properly before it not in the middle of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can match any character zero or more times followed by a hyphen `(.*-)` and use a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert that what follows are one or more digits `(?=\d+)`.

Then you could use replace with group 1 followed by a `T`

[`(.*-)(?=\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/2EcW0X/1)

Comment: I'm more than grateful.